# How to fix javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException after switching to log4j2?

Tags: java, xml-parsing, log4j2

- Switched from log4j1 to log4j2 (1.2.17 to 2.12).
- I have 5 projects that use the new log4j2. I removed the old jar for log4j1, and all the references and paths now refer to the new added jar for log4j2.
- I am using log4j2.xml to set the configuration for log4j2.
- 4 out of 5 other projects are running perfectly with the new log4j2, logging to the right file, with the correct pattern described in the `log4j2.xml` file.
- One project - let's call it "ProjectX" - is returning an error when trying to access the same logger:

`ERROR StatusLogger Caught javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException`

The following are used when running the project:

- jdk1.7.0_79
- oracle.jdbc_11.1.1\ojdbc6dms.jar;
- oracle.nlsrtl_11.1.0\orai18n.jar;
- oracle.odl_11.1.1\ojdl.jar;
- oracle.dms_11.1.1\dms.jar;
- oracle.xdk_11.1.0\xmlparserv2.jar;
- oracle.xdk_11.1.0\xml.jar;
- com.oracle.toplink_1.0.0.0_11-1-1-5-0.jar;
- org.eclipse.persistence_1.1.0.0_2-1.jar;
- com.bea.core.antlr.runtime_2.7.7.jar;
- javax.persistence_1.0.0.0_2-0-0.jar;
- wlserver_10.3\server\lib\weblogic.jar;
- commons-io-2.4.jar;
- log4j-api-2.12.0.jar;
- log4j-core-2.12.0.jar;
- wlserver_10.3\server\lib\weblogic.jar

The `log4j2.xml` I'm using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Properties>
        <!-- Path to the log files -->
        <Property name="log-path">C:/logs</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <!-- Logger that prints to the Console window -->
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>%-6p%d{DATE} - %C{1}.%M:%L - %m%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </Console>
        <!-- Logger that prints to the log file specified in the fileName -->
        <RollingFile name="LoggerFile" fileName="${log-path}/App.log" filePattern="${log-path}/App-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log" immediateFlush="true" append="true">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>%-6p%d{DATE} - %C{1}.%M:%L - %m%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <!-- The maximum size of a log file -->
            <Policies>                
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1 MB" />
            </Policies>
            <!-- Number of log files before starting to roll over -->
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="RollingFileLogger" level="DEBUG">
            <AppenderRef ref="LoggerFile"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="DEBUG">
            <AppenderRef ref="LoggerFile"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Any idea what causes the error `ERROR StatusLogger Caught javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException`?

Could it be `oracle.xdk_11.1.0\xmlparserv2.jar` or `xml.jar`?

I tried xmlparserv2.jar version 12.2, and it fixed the error.
To download version 12.2 of xmpparserv2.jar:
https://maven.oracle.com/com/oracle/jdbc/xmlparserv2/12.2.0.1/xmlparserv2-12.2.0.1.jar

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded the xmlparser jar from version 11.1 to version 12.2: xmlparserv2-12.2.0.1.jar.
I added it to the project and it fixed the problem.